# Trouble converting C++ method to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I'm trying to translate a C++ method that uses a homegrown form of encryption. But I don't understand what `Buffer[x]` and  `Input[x]` are doing? As a C# developer (beginner at that), It looks like they should be arrays but they aren't declared as such. Can anyone explain please?

The input string "{x;ƒ~sq{j|tLtuq"   translates to "MY SOFTWARE INC"

```
AnsiString __fastcall TMyMain::Decode(AnsiString Input)
{
  int error[] = { 2, 9, 5, 4, 1, 6, 7, 12, 19, 3, 1, 0, 21, 17 };
  int x;
  AnsiString Buffer = Input;

  if (encoded!=0)
  {
    int count = 0;

    for(x=Input.Length();x>=1;x--)
    {
      Buffer[x] = Input[x]-48+error[count];
      count++;
      if (count>=14)
        count=0;
    }
  }

  return Buffer;
}
```

Comment: Check out the code for `AnsiString` to see what it does.

Comment: in c++ types may overload operators in any way they like. The `Input[x]` could mean literally anything depending on what `AnsiString` is

Comment: Well in C# if you have a `string s;` then you do `s[0]` it's getting the first character of said string.  Now you cannot update `string` characters in C#, but it kinda looks like that's what's going one with `AnsiString`.

Comment: Its not my encryption.

Comment: Input is the argument to the function, and Buffer was assigned to it. They appear to be treated as character arrays, where the character at index `x` in Input is reduced by 48 and then increased by the corresponding value in the `error` array at `count` index, and then assigned to `Buffer` at the same location from where it was read in `Input`.

Comment: I don't get  "MY SOFTWARE INC", I get " "MY bOFTWARE INC".

Comment: @tobi303, To be fair, C# classes can overload `[]` as well, so that shouldn't be surprising to a C# developer, although it might be to a beginner.

Comment: @chris To be fair, I dont even know how to pronounce C# :P

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd translate it.  Note I have no idea where `encoded` comes from, so I left that out.  The trick is to use a `StringBuilder` for your buffer so you can mutate the characters, another options would be a `char` array.

```
public static string Decode(string input)
{
    int[] error = { 2, 9, 5, 4, 1, 6, 7, 12, 19, 3, 1, 0, 21, 17 };
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(input);

    int count = 0;
    for (int x = input.Length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
        buffer[x] = (char)(input[x] - 48 + error[count]);
        count++;
        if (count >= 14)
            count = 0;
    }

    return buffer.ToString();
}
```

This however outputs "MY TOFTWARE INC" for the input "{x;ƒ~sq{j|tLtuq", so I'm not exactly sure if the issue is with your string or the code.

Comment: Interesting, I get the same result using your code. But thats farther than I've gotten. Thanks!

Comment: I think the issue may be between ASCII and UNICODE now.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with this, but it doesn't quite return the expected results.  Are you sure of the input string?

Input and output is string.

```
var encoded = true;
var input = "{x;ƒ~sq{j|tLtuq";
var output = Decode(input);
Console.WriteLine($"input \"{input}\", output \"{output}\"");

private static string Decode(string input)
{
    int[] error = { 2, 9, 5, 4, 1, 6, 7, 12, 19, 3, 1, 0, 21, 17 };
    var buffer = new char[input.Length];

    if (encoded)
    {
        int count = 0;

        for(var x=input.Length-1;x>=0;x--)
        {
            buffer[x] = (char) ((Convert.ToInt16(input[x])-48 + error[count]) & 0xFF);
            count++;
            if (count>=error.Length)
                count=0;
        }
        return new string(buffer)
    }
    return input;
}
```

Calling this writes the following to the console:

> input "{x;ƒ~sq{j|tLtuq", output "MY bOFTWARE INC"

Comment: Yes input string is correct. But after some more Googling it looks like C++ uses ASCII and C# is UNICODE based. This may be the issue with the mistranslation. It's all new to me as far as that goes.

Comment: Thinking about this more... the issue is that the encrypted data is ANSI, or more probably Windows code page 1252 [Wikipedia Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).  That fourth charater in the encoded string, lower-case f with hook, causes this issue to exhibit itself.  If possible, perhaps you can convert the encrypted data from Windows-1252 to Unicode, then convert that to ASCII for decoding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps but after some reverse engeneering you could use the following errors array (with the StringBuilder implementation) to dispaly the proper information.

```
int[] error = { 2, 9, 5, 4, 1, 6, 7, 12, 19, 3, 1, -6, 21, 17 };//MY SOFTWARE INC
```

It has to do with how characters were encoded in c++ vs c# so you could try to play around with `System.Text.Encoding`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that tomorrow.